# How to suspend a process and save state for after reboot

Tags: processing

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

I'm trying to run some long scans which can take days to finish. The scans I'm using don't have a pause, save and continue function and I'd rather not break them up into smaller steps.

Using `kill -STOP $PID` only works **without** rebooting, requiring the system to stay either on or hibernated, and I'd like to be able to shutdown my PC. I've also tried using VirtualBox but it freezes if left unattended for a long time and I'd like to keep it running even without human interaction.

Are there some ways I can freeze/suspend a process and continue it even after shutting down/rebooting my PC?

Comment: Not that I have an answer to this, but are we supposed to *guess* what platform you are running on?

Comment: We have not been playing around with Zombies long enough, @John Zhau, but we would suggest that you could start by investigating the Notion of _Core Dumps_. When a Process is failing, sometimes - depending on some Settings of the Operating System -, what happens is that a certain Image of the Process is saved on the Hard Disk Drive. If it were possible for you to force the dumping of such a Process Image and then its subsequent reloading from the Hard Disk Drive whenever you feel like, then you are all set.

Comment: Using a VM is the way to do it (maybe a docker with checkpoint too). It is not normal for virtualbox to freeze, you might want to investigate that instead.